# Отслеживать селекторы, которые выводятся динамически на странице с помощью php

Tags: php, jquery

У меня проблема. Есть радио кнопки, которые выводятся в цикле на `php`, необходимо отслеживать `id` - который подставляется динамически. То есть первая часть `id` - это слово, вторая код из базы данных. Мне по клику нужно выбрать именно тот радио `button`, который выбран на `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы срабатывали события типа `click` на существующих и подгружаемых элементах, вешайте событие не на класс, идентификатор или элемент, а на `document`.

Пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.alert', () => alert('Сработал!'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert">Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На будущее, оставляйте код, так будете понятнее + ответ вы получите и быстрее, и качественнее.

Лично я из вашего вопроса ничего не понял, осмелюсь предположить, что Вам нужно проверить состояние input-radio, но это не точно..

```js
// Перебераем все элементы у которого id начинается с "slovo_"
$('[id^="slovo_"]').each(function(){
  // Далее проверяем "чекнут" ли этот элемент
  let checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  // Здесь можете выполнять свои действия, я просто для демо укажу под каждый radio его checked
  $('label').eq($(this).index() - 1).text(checked);
});
```

```css
input, label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---->
<input id="slovo_1" type="radio" checked>
<input id="slovo_two" type="radio">
<input id="slovo_3333" type="radio" checked>
<input id="slovo_asdq312da" type="radio">
<input id="slovo_##@!@#" type="radio">
<input id="slovo_kek" type="radio" checked>
<br><br>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
```

Comment: $("._cart2-step-cont .check_class").map(function(indx, element){
   var num_id = $("._cart2-step-cont .check_class").attr("id").substring(12);
   if($("#deliv_check_" + num_id).prop("checked") === false){
    $("#p_deliv").text("Необходимо выбрать способ доставки");
   return false;
   }
   else{
    $("#p_deliv").addClass("display_none");
   }
  });

Comment: Вот код, я видимо как то его не так добавил

Comment: @Владислав, мой ответ вам в кассу. У вас же не срабатывает событие на вновь добавленных? Код в вопрос надо добавлять.

Comment: @ doox911 К сожалению ваш код, точно так же видит только первую кнопку.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 вы правильно поняли все, но он видит только первый элемент и вашим кодом тоже.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Нашёл ошибку, ваш код работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Владислав, если мой ответ вам помог, то выберите его как "правильный ответ"