# Подскажите пожалуйста альтернативу события On() Jquery на чистом js

Tags: javascript

C помощью **js** я на страницу добавляю несколько тегов **div** с классом `test`, как мне создать обработчик клика на каждый из вновь добавленных `div`. На `Jquery` я бы воспользовался функцией `on()`:

```
$('body').on('click','.test',function(){
  alert('вы нажали на див');
});
```

А как такое можно сделать на чистом **js** ?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отслеживать селекторы, которые выводятся динамически на странице с помощью php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001003/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-php)

Comment: @doox911 если и дубликат, то явно не данного вопроса

Comment: @СергейМишин, согласен, не нашел где отменить)

Comment: Повесьте слушатель на родителя и делегируйте события

Comment: слушатель на родителя это что то вроде document.body.addEventListener?

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется писать на чистом JS то есть хороший сайт http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
Касательно именно .on то вот как её можно заменить.

```
function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function(){
      handler.call(el);
    });
  }
}

addEventListener(el, eventName, handler);
```

Comment: вопрос больше про делегацию события, но ссылка годная по-этому плюс

Comment: Ссылка и в прям  достойная внимания....

Comment: Ссылка хоть и хорошая, но на поставленный вопрос не отвечает :)

Comment: Почему не отвечает? просто полный  код на чистом JS будет излишним, к тому-же я немного отошел от JS но увидел вопрос который так-же решал ибо не очень любил из-за небольшого удобства тащить кучу библиотек, я был сторонником чистого JS там где это допустимо.