# Как показать в какую именно таблицу я делаю UPDATE или INSERT INTO значений, если пишу эти значения в html и передаю ajax'ом?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю чистильщик текста под свои нужды. При подгрузке файла или вставке происходит обращения к базе, и текст чистится согласно значениям в таблицах. Есть пока 5 таблиц Удаляемые фразы (удаляет в строках значения, найденные в этой таблице), Оставляемые фразы (удаляет в строке все кроме найденных строк), Автозамена (заменяет найденное на другое значение) и т.д. На странице Настройки есть список таблиц и при клике на каждую динамически выводятся значения в `<table>`.

Пока что значения я добавляю (или исправляю) в phpmyadmin, но т.к. это хлопотно хочу сделать ajax'ом. Над каждой таблицей есть строка `<td contenteditable="true">...</td>`, которая по js-событию `onchange` будет добавлять новое значение в базу. То есть, переключился в первую таблицу-добавил, переключился во вторую-добавил. Но, как начинающий, не могу допереть, как показать в какую таблицу добавляются значения из html в базу, если так можно прыгать по таблицам по клику. За что зацепиться, чтобы передать название таблицы, новое значение в строке дальше в базу и, соответственно, увидеть обновленную базу здесь же? Спасибо!

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-bar">
  <ul class="tables">
   <li id="DeleteAll">Удаляемые фразы</li>
   <li id="DeleteAllExcept">Оставляемые фразы</li>
   <li id="FindReplace">Автозамена</li>
   <li id="RealNames">Имена собственные</li>
   <li id="Users">Пользователь</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <table id="DeleteAllExcept">
  <tr><td><input id="inputRow" type="text" placeholder="Добавить..." onchange="myFunc(this.value)"></td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>Биатлон. Кубок мира</pre></td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>Искры камина</pre></td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>"Я стесняюсь своего тела"</pre></td></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Укажите конкретику. Что конкретно не получается. А так это слишком общий вопрос.

Comment: Ок, как я себе представляю. Я, например, могу задать id для table, например, для Автозамены `<table id='FindReplace'>`. Затем в json передать id на сервер, а там сделать что-то вроде "если id == FindReplace, то запрос будет "INSERT INTO `findReplace`...". Но правильно ли я себе представляю?

Comment: Или ладно, как передать и название таблицы, и новое значение, которое попадет в таблицу? Причем сначала клик по списку таблиц слева, затем пишем значение. Затем событие onchange и нужная таблица обновилась...

Comment: Код `html` приведите. И я сделаю,

Comment: @doox911, а как, если таблица динамически формируется?)

Comment: Повесить событие на `document`

Comment: А подробнее `document.onready = '?'`. Что нужно прописать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001003/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-php/1001011#1001011

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. В данном случае я нажал на `li#DeleteAllExcept` в `ul.tables`: `div.main` заполнился таблицей `table#DeleteAllExcept` со значениями. Первый `tr` с `input` служит для добавления нового значения в базу и мгновенного обновления текущей table.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', () => {
  let val = $('#inputRow').val();
  if(val.length > 0){
    $('.tables').append(`<li class="item">${val}</li>`)
    
    // Тут можно отправить запрос в на сервер!
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  
  // Тут можно отправить запрос в на сервер!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-bar">
  <ul class="tables">
   <li id="DeleteAll" class="item">Удаляемые фразы</li>
   <li id="DeleteAllExcept" class="item">Оставляемые фразы</li>
   <li id="FindReplace" class="item">Автозамена</li>
   <li id="RealNames" class="item">Имена собственные</li>
   <li id="Users" class="item">Пользователь</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <table id="DeleteAllExcept">
  <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="inputRow" type="text">
        <input type="submit"name="addli" value="Добавить">
      </td>
     </tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>Биатлон. Кубок мира</pre></td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>Искры камина</pre></td></tr>
  <tr><td contenteditable="true"><pre>"Я стесняюсь своего тела"</pre></td></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как на сервер передать название таблицы (например, DeleteAllExcept) и значение из input, чтобы потом сформировать `INSERT INTO DeleteAllExcept (some columns) values (input.value)`? Ну, скажем, в json?

Comment: @forever_young — это уже другой вопрос. Ответ: так же. Там где  `$(document)` добавьте запрос.